# How do I mount a UFS disk in read-write mode?

Tags: filesystems, freebsd, freenas

I have a system drive that has filled up to the last sector, so that it doesn't boot anymore. The file system is UFS (it's an old Freenas 0.7 installation), but since UFS write support doesn't appear to be included in any linux distro I figured I get a live CD of FreeBSD to mount it.

The problem is that all the live CDs I try, be it FreeBSD, FreeNAS or Nas4free, none of them seem to be able to mount a UFS file system. From what I've read, this is what I'm supposed to do:

```
mount -t ufs -w -o ufstype=ufs2 /dev/wd0 /mnt/rescue
```

But this only yields:

```
mount: no mount helper program found for ufs: No such file or directory
```

And if you look in `/sbin` you see only the following (non-mount related files omitted):

```
mount_cd9660
mount_ext2fs
mount_ffs
mount_msdos
mount_udf
```

Which I assume all are the helpers mount is referring to. All the different live CDs I've tried have the same repertoire of helpers. I thought UFS was the default file system in FreeBSD, so I feel that I'm missing something fundamental here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get hold of a Solaris install disk. This should be enough to get you into a root shell and allow you to mount the drive.

The [Solaris file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_File_System#Implementations%20Solaris%20file%20system) is UFS and will provide you with the support you need.